# zero value after build in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

in my class extend ConstraintLayout. I have defined val-type variables in the class. 
After running the program in the debug mode, I see that all the variables are zero.
Why is this going to happen?

[image]

Comment: try 'execute command' mode and find out what the current value it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define variables with initializers, the Kotlin compiler will generate a constructor which will execute all the initializers in sequence. Before the initializers are executed, the values of the corresponding fields will be 0, and this is the state that is shown on your screenshot.

For values such as `IMEOPTIONS_ACTION_DONE`, which seem to be constants, you shouldn't use regular class properties. Instead, you should put them into a `companion object` or on the top level of a file.